# How can align text to the right using VBA, if a cell contains a specific value?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to fix a spreadsheet, so that if the word TRAVEL is in a cell, then the contents of the cell is right justified.

I have looked into what VBA code is generated when you right justify (.HorizonalAlignment = xlRight) but I feel my implementation is the issue.

I am also confining it to a certain range (A3 - A101)

```
Private Sub CellHasTravel()
  If Range("A3:A101").Value == "TRAVEL" Then
    .HorizonalAlignment = xlRight
  End If
End Sub
```

I was expecting this code to actually right justify a cell, but instead I am presented with

> Compile Error: Syntax error

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use just one `=` sign.

Comment: `Range("A3:A101").Value` - this is an array for a multi-cell range, and comparing to `"TRAVEL"` will fail. Loop through each cell.

Comment: And `.HorizontalAlignment` does not seem to be related to any object.

Comment: You need a loop over all of the (individual) cells in that range. Then, use all of the above comments :)

Comment: Instead of looping though every cell use `.Find` and `.FindNext` as shown [Here](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/11/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) and then change the alignment. It will be much faster...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub travel()

Dim cells As Range

For Each cells In ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A101")

    If cells.Value = "TRAVEL" Then

        cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    Else
    End If
Next cells


End Sub
```

Hope you find usefull and I could help.

Comment: To add to this if TRAVEL is not always uppercase in the range you can use:
If UCase(cells.Value) = "TRAVEL" Then